# How to decrement the time in the below code till it becomes zero?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a timestamp countdown by giving time and date in milliseconds, but I am not able to solve this.

```
var distance = countDownDate--
```

only decrements the number one time. I want to decrement it till zero like time counter.

```js
// Set the date we're counting down to
var d = new Date();
d.setTime(405000000);
var countDownDate = d;

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  //this line decrementing only by one time, but I need till the time becomes zero
  var distance = countDownDate--;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " +
    minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

  // If the count down is over, write some text 
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
```

```css
p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code actually **works**.

The problem is, that `difference` is in *milliseconds*, and you decrement it by one every *second*. So, if you hung around for 1000 seconds (ca. 17 minutes), you'd see the counter decrease by 1 second.

To solve it, subtract `1000` in each iteration:

```js
// Set the date we're counting down to
var d = new Date();
d.setTime(405000000);
var countDownDate = d;

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  //this line deceremneting only by one time, but I need till the time becomes zero
  var distance = countDownDate -= 1000;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " +
    minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

  // If the count down is over, write some text 
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
```

```css
p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

However, `setTimeout` and `setInterval` may be inaccurate, so it's recommended to get the current time every iteration:

```js
// Set the date we're counting down to
var endDate = Date.now() + 405000000;

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  //this line deceremneting only by one time, but I need till the time becomes zero
  var distance = endDate - Date.now();

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " +
    minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

  // If the count down is over, write some text 
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
```

```css
p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your distance is milliseconds so you need to subtract 1000 every second

Try this

```js
const pad = num => ("0"+num).slice(-2);

// Set the date we're counting down to
var countdownDate = new Date();
countdownDate.setTime(5000000);
let distance = countdownDate.getTime();


// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {
  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + pad(hours) + "h " +
    pad(minutes) + "m " + pad(seconds) + "s ";

  distance-=1000;
  // If the count down is over, write some text 
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
```

```css
p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```